# understanding move semantic for a shared_ptr with an rvalue function call

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

In the following small program I have two examples of using `move` with `shared_ptr`.

The first example behaves as I expected and the ownership of the `shared_ptr` `p` is assigned to the new pointer `p2`. After the assignment `p` is an invalid pointer.

I would expect the same to happen also in the second example, but it does not. The precise questions are embedded as comments in the source code. What is wrong in my reasoning?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(shared_ptr<int>&& p)
{
    std::cout << "zoo: " << p.use_count() << "\n";
    // when this function terminates, should the destructor of p
    // decrement the ref counter and destroy the pointed object?
}

void example1()
{
    auto p = make_shared<int>(0);
    std::cout << "count before move: " << p.use_count() << "\n";
    shared_ptr<int> p2(move(p));
    std::cout << "count after move: " << p.use_count() << "\n";  // output 0: ownership transferred to p2
}

void example2()
{
    auto p = make_shared<int>(0);
    std::cout << "count before move: " << p.use_count() << "\n";
    foo(move(p));
    std::cout << "count after move: " << p.use_count() << "\n";
    // output 1: Why is this not zero?
    //Why has ownership not transferred to the argument of the function foo? 
}

int main()
{
    example1();
    example2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::move()` is not really a move - it's actually an rvalue reference cast. The argument `p` of `foo()` isn't moved anywhere in `foo()`. Hence, it stays in `p`. If you add your `p2` line in `foo()` you will achieve the effect you're looking for: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfce459cc463375f)

Comment: The `std::move` says "you are allowed to move this object".  It does not mean the object **will** be taken, just that it **may** be taken.  The example's `foo` routine does not take the object that is allowed to be moved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why has ownership not transferred to the argument of the function foo?

Because the parameter type of `foo` is an *rvalue reference* of `shared_ptr`, no new `shared_ptr` object is created, the `p` in `foo` is just a *reference* to the original `p` which is *not* moved to any object.

If you change `foo` to *pass by value*, a new `shared_ptr` object is created, then you will find that `p` has been moved:

```
void foo(shared_ptr<int> p)
{
    //...
}
foo(move(p)); // ownership transferred
```